# GWT Client: sending a file with multipart/form-data post request

Tags: gwt, cordova, post, http-post, multipartform-data

I have already tried a lot of approaches to send a xml file as string + pictures with a POST request using GWT on the client side. I can send the strings successfully, but I do not know how to send files (pictures) using the RequestBuilder, I am just able to send the strings.

Do someone know how to send files with a multipart/form-data POST request using GWT Client (RequestBuilder)?

P.S.: As I am not wishing to upload files, I don't need a uploader or something similar. I am developing a mobile app with Phonegap, and making pictures, which should be sent per POST request to a server (a third party service).

Thanks in advance!

Here some code:

```
public void sendPost() throws RequestException {
        String boundary = createBoundary();
        String xml = "<note> <to>Müller</to> <from>Jani</from> <heading>Erinnerung</heading> <body>Ich wohne in der Leipzigerstraße</body> </note>";
        String requestData = getRequestData(boundary, xml);



    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, "http://localhost:8080/xxx/yyy");
    builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=" + boundary);
    builder.setHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(requestData.length()));
    try {
      builder.sendRequest(requestData, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {

        }
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
          exception.printStackTrace();
        }
      });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private String getRequestData(String boundary, String xml) {
    String s = "";

    s += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    s += getRequestParameter("xml", xml + "");
    s += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n"; // end
    return s;
}

private String getRequestParameter(String key, String value) {
    return "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"\r\n\r\n"
            + value + "\r\n";
}
private String createBoundary() {
    return "----GoneVerticalBoundary" + getRandomStr() + getRandomStr();
}

private String getRandomStr() {
    return Long.toString(random.nextLong(), 36); //random -> DEFINED IN THE CLASS BODY
}
```

Comment: If you have an idea how you'd do that in JS, then _porting_ it to GWT should be straightforward. But GWT cannot do miracles.

Comment: +1 on question. Not come across the use case. Also retagged with phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using gwt + phonegap you should be using gwt-phonegap, right?

What I do in my apps, is to use gwtupload for the desktop version, and phonegap file transfer in the mobile. I use gwtupload servlet in the server side for both cases.

This is my code using gwt-phonegap:

```
  FileUploadOptions options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.setFileKey("file");
  options.setFileName("my_file.txt");
  options.setMimeType("text/plain");

  phonegap.getFile().createFileTransfer().upload(
   "file:///my_path/my_file.txt", 
   "http://my-gwtupload-servlet/servlet.gupld", 
   options, 
   new FileUploadCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileUploadResult result) {
      if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      } else {
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(FileTransferError error) {
      Window.alert("Error sending the file, error-code: " + error.getCode());
    }
  });
```

I use deferred binding for selecting the appropriate implementation using `phonegap.env`:

```
<replace-with class="...UploadFilePhoneGap">
  <when-type-is class="....UploadFile" />
  <when-property-is name="phonegap.env" value="yes" />
</replace-with>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for pure gwt solution then you need to work with [FileUpload](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html)

If you do not mind using third party open source jar then you can try [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/)

For locale issues just ensure you are using UTF-8 and GWT locale cookies and locale settings.

Comment: I have already used gwtupload before, but now I am developing for a mobile phone with phonegap, so you can't just upload pictures (files) there. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could you update your question with details about phonegap , gwtupload and also any other approach you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

For all the people who wants to manage files and pictures on the client side, before sending them to the server, as Manolo has recommended, I suggest [lib-gwt-file](http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-file).

For people working with PhoneGap, I suggest enconding the pictures using Base64, and decoding on the server side (see class [Base64Util](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwt_hmtl5))